# REST: return ok on put with additional info about data

Tags: rest, http

I have an API resource for user profile (consumed by mobile app). User can submit data via PUT and get response. In case of incorrect data I return 422 and error explanation, otherwise 200.

But there is one state of data which is correct in terms of domain logic, but requires manual intervention by admin. In this case the request is successful, but I need to show user a message that his situation is exceptional and will be investigated by admin.

The question is: how can I do this RESTfully? 202 status? Or just 200 and plain text message? Or create another resource like profile/verify and use it right after submitting new data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. HTTP 202 is a good fit for this scenario. As you can read in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3)

> The 202 (Accepted) status code indicates that **the request has been
>
> accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.
>
> The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might
>
> be disallowed when processing actually takes place.**  There is no
> facility in HTTP for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous
> operation.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally noncommittal.  **Its purpose is
> to    allow a server to accept a request** for some other process
> (perhaps a    batch-oriented process that is only run once per day)
> **without    requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist    until the process is completed.**  **The representation
> sent with this    response ought to describe the request's current
> status** and point to    (or embed) a status monitor that can provide
> the user with an    estimate of when the request will be fulfilled.

Emphasis mine.

So you should send a response with a 202 status in the header, and a message describing the reason to inform the user that the request is valid and being processed and that **he should not repeat the request.**

> But there is one state of data which is correct in terms of domain logic, but requires manual intervention by admin.

This corresponds to

> The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might
> be disallowed when processing actually takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I think 202 fits here.

From the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) `[202 Accepted]: The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation such as this.`

Unfortunately, the [RFC for `PUT`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) does not mention async processing of requests. I think 202 is a valid solution for this case (but that's just my opinion). At the end of they day it's always best to talk to your API consumers and see what they think.